# How to fix "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 provider cannot be used in Visual Studio because it is 32-bit only" in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: ms-access, oledb, visual-studio-2022

I need to add a database to my GUI and this is the error that appears whenever I test the connection, and the other problem is that I can't import Microsoft Access database to Visual Studio:

[image: error message]

I already fixed the error of "Microsoft Jet Oledb Provider Not Registered On Local Machine" and I tried to test the connection and its successful but whenever I tried to import the MS-Access database, it doesn't appear. Now I have this problem.

Comment: You can't mx 32- and 64-bit.  Target your app for 32-bit, or find a 64-bit provider.

Answer (score 2):

While what Dave S. said in [their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76425344/how-to-fix-microsoft-jet-oledb-4-0-provider-cannot-be-used-in-visual-studio-bec/76426131#comment134761522_76425344) is true, I think in this case it is because [Visual Studio 2022 is 64-bit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/whats-new-visual-studio-2022?view=vs-2022#visual-studio-2022-is-64-bit).  It is the first version of Visual Studio that is 64-bit rather than 32-bit.

The error message *sort of* indicates that with the way it is worded:

> The Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 provider cannot be used in *Visual Studio* because it is 32-bit only.

Note how is specifically says *Visual Studio*.

If you go to the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/accessing-data-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2022#data-providers) that is in that error message, it states:

> If you're using Visual Studio to connect to databases using OLEDB or ODBC data providers, you will need to be aware that versions of Visual Studio prior to Visual Studio 2022 are all 32-bit processes. This means some of the data tools in Visual Studio will only be able to connect to OLEDB or ODBC databases using 32-bit data providers. This includes the Microsoft Access 32-bit OLEDB data provider as well as other third-party 32-bit providers.
>
> If you're using Visual Studio 2022 to connect to databases, you will need to be aware that Visual Studio 2022 is a 64-bit process. This means some of the data tools in Visual Studio will not be able to connect to OLEDB or ODBC databases using 32-bit data providers.
>
> If you need to maintain 32-bit applications that connect to OLEDB or ODBC databases, you will still be able to build and run the application with Visual Studio 2022. However, if you need to use any of the Visual Studio Data Tools such as Server Explorer, Data Source Wizard, or the DataSet Designer, you will need to use an earlier version of Visual Studio that is still a 32-bit process. The last version of Visual Studio that was a 32-bit process was Visual Studio 2019.

By the looks of it, you are using the "Data Source Wizard" (that is my guess at least), which according to this page, you won't be able to do in Visual Studio 2022 since it is not 32-bit.

Comment: Makes sense, and the question is much clearer after your edits.  As you say I was thinking of the application not Visual Studio's own tools.

Comment: You can still with relative ease use Access JET/ACE x32, and I been doing this since the day vs2022 came out. See my explain below.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the soluiton in most cases then is to use the x64 bit version of the Access data base engine.

the older JET data engine is limited to using .mdb files. And this choice is ONLY x32 bits

While the newer ACE data engine can open both .mdb and accDB files?
It is ALSO available in x32 bits, or x64 bits.

Regardless of you using VS 2022 (x64 bits), or previous versions that are x32 bits?

You can STILL USE the x32 bit verison of JET, and you can STILL USE the x32 bit verison of ACE.

And you cna STILL USE that JET engine in vs2022.

However, this will mean that some of the data wizards will not work (such as ones to create a gridview).

So, you can STILL however in code use JET or ACE, and you CAN STILL use JET or ACE EVEN with vs2022.

So, first up:

in the data connection, (and I assume we doing this from settings, NOT a wizard for say a gridview).

Then you see this:

[image]

DO NOT use test connection here!!!

However, to select JET or ACE, then click on advanced in above:

[image]

So, note how we can choose JET (older x32 only), or ACE. (newer, comes in both x32 and x64).

Ok, so if you actually see the ACE choice, then that means you have a x32 driver installed.

ONE MORE HUGE important step here:

Since you may well be wnating to use access x32 (ACE), then you MUST force your project to run as x32 (x86).

That is this setting:

[image]

So, in summary:

Yes, even with vs2022, you CAN use JET and you CAN use the x32 bit verison of JET. This will mean ONLY mdb files, and not accDB files.

yes, even with vs2022, you CAN use ACE and you CAN use the x32 bit version of ACE. This will mean that you can open both mdb and accdb files.

And if you want the wizards to work in vs2022, then you CAN and SHOULD install ACE x64 bits, as that will mean:

The test conneciton will now work, and the wizards should also work assuming you using and connecting to a accDB file.

however, even if you DO NOT use test connection (when using JET or x32 ACE), when you run the project, and ASSUMING you forced the project to x32 bits, then your code and use of JET OR ACE will work, will work EVEN if you using x32 JET or ACE. The only thing that will not work is the test connection, and as noted, then some of the wizards.

however, any code that opens and uses the database will work, and will work even when using vs2022.

All in all, since I don't use the wizards much, but I MOST certainly do use the conneciton wizard and setup as above screen shots show, then I am able to use access databases without any much issues - even in vs2022.

Because I am still doing a lot of access development, then I have NOT upgraded my version of Access to x64 bit version, but that would be the best solution here, since then even the wizards and connecting testing in vs2022 will now work.

So, for now, SKIP the test connection in above screen shot, and if you not requiring the data wizards for a grid view etc., then you can quite much work in vs2022 without issues, and WHEN you run the project, the connections will work.